# Splitting PDFs in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf.js, hummus.js

I am looking for a way to split PDFs, not by pages, but based on specific sections that I can detect with a regex pattern in NodeJS.

I have attempted to use Muhammara/HummusJS but they only seem to split by pages. I've also looked into other libraries like pdfjs-dist but I could not find support for splitting